# Android firebase authentication for all app users using single email ID

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an app which accesses Firebase database and storage using email based Authentication. Is it possible to use single email ID/passwd for all the users using my app? The email ID and password are harcoded in the method shown below which is called from onCreate. This works fine while testing with one device. I have seen authentication issues although not consistent while trying from different Android devices on different API versions. I just wanted to rule out if there is any limitation in using single email ID/passwd for accessing the app/database from different devices?

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("email ID", "password")
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
  public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)     {
  System.out.println("AUTH signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

  if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
  System.out.println("AUTH signInWithEmail:failed" + task.getException());
     }
   }
 });
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want users to create accounts or are you logging them in only just to get access for the resources on Firebase?

Comment: i have my database hosted on firebase. Users are required to access the data. I don't need to create user accounts.

Comment: Ok I'll write an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of hard-coding the user-id/password. I recommend you the **Firebase Anonymous Account**. In future, when you add support for other Auth providers like Gmail, Facebook, Twitter,. etc; You would be able to link their anonymous account with sign-in credentials.

It's super easy to convert an anonymous account to a permanent account

Refer more details about Anonymous account below,
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth

> You can use Firebase Authentication to create and use temporary
>   anonymous accounts to authenticate with Firebase. These temporary
>   anonymous accounts can be used to allow users who haven't yet signed
>   up to your app to to work with data protected by security rules. If an
>   anonymous user decides to sign up to your app, you can link their
>   sign-in credentials to the anonymous account so that they can continue
>   to work with their protected data in future sessions.

```
mAuth.signInAnonymously()
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                Log.d(TAG, "signInAnonymously:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInAnonymously", task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(AnonymousAuthActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                // ...
            }
        });
```

Hope that helps!